# What's the equivalent of PHP's "$my_array[]" in Python?

Tags: php, python

What's the equivalent of PHP's "append to array" (`$my_array[] = "abc";`) in Python, which I have recently started learning?

Let's say that I've a dictionary like this:

```
my_dict = {'fruits':['orange', 'pear']}
```

And now I want to add another fruit to `my_dict['fruits']`: `apple`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python is great for experimenting and helping you find things like this, and as you already know roughly what you're looking for (just named/termed differently), then here's a tip that should make it a bit easier for you...

```
>>> my_dict = {'fruits':['orange', 'pear']}
>>> type(my_dict['fruits'])
<type 'list'>
```

So we know that it's list (in this case the built-in list type)... We know we want to "add" something to it... So let's look at what it offers...

```
>>> dir(list)
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__delslice__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__setslice__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'append', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']
```

`insert`, `extend` and `append` look useful... Let's see what it says...

```
>>> help(list.extend)
Help on method_descriptor:

extend(...)
    L.extend(iterable) -- extend list by appending elements from the iterable
```

Doesn't sound quite right...

```
>>> help(list.insert)
Help on method_descriptor:

insert(...)
    L.insert(index, object) -- insert object before index
```

Seems a little specific about positioning...

```
>>> help(list.append)
Help on method_descriptor:

append(...)
    L.append(object) -- append object to end
```

Hey, looking good :)

It just so happens that in this instance, you could just do `help(my_dict['fruits'])`...

Answer (score 8):

[`.append()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) adds new elements:

```
my_dict = {'fruits':['orange', 'pear']}
my_dict['fruits'].append('apple')
```

Comment: Simple answer, nicely written

Comment: Cool, thanks. Must wait additional 8 minutes to accept the answer.

Comment: And you've already found out why there is a delay before you accept an answer. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for the straight forward answer. But @Jon Clements had a bit more details on his.